# How do I resize partitions using the simple installation wizard (installing a second Ubuntu)?

Tags: installation, partitioning, re-installation, ubiquity

I'm running 11.10 and installing 12.04 LTS Beta 1 off a DVD. Using the installation wizard, I picked "Install 12.04 LTS alongside 11.10".

I am presented with a slider with approx 240GB on the left side and 60GB on the right. No other labels are present. I don't want to use the advanced partitioning tool. Which side is which Ubuntu?

[image: Allocate drive space by dragging the divider below BUT WHICH IS WHICH?]

If it's relevant: I am installing only for testing purposes (I've been caught by kernel regressions before), so I want to give 12.04 the minimal amount of space required. Once the final release is made, and I've tested that too, my plan is to remove the second partition and upgrade 11.10 to 12.04.

Comment: The left side is the current installation and the right is the one you would be installing. But, just to be sure, I am confirming it.

Comment: @jokerdino thanks for taking the time to confirm it, I don't feel comfortable continuing not knowing!

Comment: created a usability bug to help avoid this question in future :) https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/947107

Comment: I now confirm my previous statement. Just tried a live CD.

Comment: @jokerdino thanks! please add it as an answer (and if you don't mind, explain how you confirmed it)

Comment: I ran into the same question, as I wanted to reserve most of the disk space for windows. I believe the partitian to the right will be the one used by Ubuntu, but not sure yet. I did find one interesting thing though. When you click next and then grab the title bar of the next msg box, and slide it around, graphics appear in the two gray boxes that you have just defined. The graphics appear to confirm that the right side partition is the Ubuntu partition, but the verbiage on the graphics is itself a bit ambiguous.

Comment: I think this is just the same bug whether it's windows/ubuntu or ubuntu/ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

When logged in on 11.10, open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type the following:

```
cat /etc/mtab
```

There you will find which partitions are currently mounted. The first is the location of the partition (for instance: **/dev/sda2**), the second parameter gives you where it is mounted.
Look for **/** or **/home/**.

Write down the partitions (/dev/...).

Reboot from the DVD. The partitions you wrote down were used for 11.10, so you don't want to touch that. The /dev/... you didnt saw before is the new partition made for 12.04.

Comment: I think these instructions would help for using the advanced partition manager, but I'm trying to avoid that - the simple partition manager just shows two grey blocks separated by a slider - the only labels they have are the sizes, no "/dev/sda1", "Ubuntu 11.10", or anything like that - I'll try get a screenshot and add it to the question

Comment: Ah ofcourse, then indeed there isn't a possibility to know for sure. You could assume it is the one most to the right, but that is just a guess.